# UIViewController status bar top inset

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

I'm using `SCPageViewController` in my app:

```
class RootPageViewController: UIViewController {

    var pageViewController : SCPageViewController = SCPageViewController()

    var viewControllers = [UIViewController]() 
    ......
```

in viewDidLoad I'm configuring it:

```
self.pageViewController.setLayouter(SCPageLayouter(), animated: false, completion: nil)
self.pageViewController.easingFunction = SCEasingFunction(type: SCEasingFunctionType.linear) 
self.pageViewController.dataSource = self;
self.pageViewController.delegate = self;
self.addChildViewController(self.pageViewController)
self.pageViewController.view.frame = self.view.bounds
self.view.addSubview(self.pageViewController.view)
self.pageViewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

I'm setting size of content view controllers in SCPageViewController data source method to be size of RootPageViewController. When app launches, I have my "status bar" that is just plain UIView with background color behind system status bar. But when I'm scrolling to next/previous page, it is offset by few pixels. How I can unify that? Why I'm getting this small offset on top?

I'm using Storyboards to model view controllers:

[image: Storyboard]

This is how it looks after app launches (as expected):

[image: expected]

And when I scroll to next page:

[image]

This white area shouldn't be there... Everything is fine after I rotate device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change the `originY` for the view to move it up a bit:

```
yourView.frame.origin.y = -5
```

BUT you should take a look at your `constraints` and see what happens to them when you change view and see if you could solve it that way instead. Because the solution provided above will move up the view, so you will have - 5 pixels at the bottom.

Comment: Constants look Ok, after rotating device to landscape and back to portrait it snap back magically to top like it should.. so setting -5 will make it offset up after rotating. All view controllers have status bar constraint set to 0 on top

Comment: Try to do this in your `viewWillAppear` `yourView.layoutIfNeeded`

Comment: Not helping. I have checked interface in xCode by capturing it - Main UIView is on whole screen just content inside have this offset.

Comment: I'm moving my status bar to `frame.origin.y` 0 and calling `view.layoutIfNeeded` on whole view controller. Looks perfect. Danke:)

Comment: @Preetygeek, great! Good luck with your project and layout =)